# PCB Assembly: Specifying Jumper Configuration For Assembly House

Tags: pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, jumper

I want to send a board off for fab + assembly soon which will include various jumpers in 2 or 3 pin configurations. For example, see this picture below (sorry about quality). I'd like to specify the 2P header to have a jumper installed, and for the 3P header, the jumper is installed on pins 1-2.

[image: jumper configuration example]

Is there any standard way of specifying this in either the BOM, Gerbers, or elsewhere? At prototype levels I can install them myself but at production this is infeasible. I'm sure worst case I can include a readme file with assembly notes.

Comment: Do you have any mechanical drawings to accompany the gerbers and BOM? Generally you should include mechanical drawings, on which you can add notes saying "place jumper between position 1 & 2" or the like. Then just be in close contact with your manufacturer and make sure they know the note is there and what it means

Comment: Worst case, yes, you could add a readme file, but it's much better for the manufacturer to be able to *see* what you're referring to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gerbers are not the right place to put such information, as they are meant for PCB manufacture only.

I would create an Assembly Drawing document that shows how components are placed and add any necessary notes for jumpers.

Here's a snippet from one of my assembly drawings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this sounds familiar.... =P

Comment: @DerStrom8 I would probably have moved on, if you had posted your comment as an answer :)

Comment: Fair enough, you got me there ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems like assembly drawing is the cleanest way to do it. Marked as the answer.