# How to draw detailed assembly outline

Tags: altium, assembly, mechanical, mechanical-assembly

How do you draw this detailed mechanical/assembly outline? I saw this at this pdf from Altium
https://resources.altium.com/sites/default/files/uberflip_docs/file_1195.pdf

[image: Altium detailed mechanical outline]

Comment: It's one of the layers when you make the footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I followed to generate the assembly drawing shown below (taken from my [other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/253783/1878)):

1. When designing the footprint, add the desired detail to the chosen mechanical layers. You may want to include things like detailed component outline, pin numbers etc.
2. Create an output job that generates the assembly drawings from the mechanical layers used above. You may choose to also include copper pads/traces, depending on what you need.
3. Run the output job to generate the PDFs

**How to draw the accurate outlines for complex parts**

The trick I use is to import a 3D model, then place markers in 3D view at corners/vertices of the part. Then go back to the 2D view and just draw the lines between the placed markers. Once done, you can remove the 3D markers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking.

1. You can import that PDF file into a Gerber editor and then work on it
2. You can import that PDF file into a mechanical CAD or Adobe Illustrator and then export it as a DXF or DWG file.
   After that you can use a Gerber editor